# How can I declare an empty variable?

Tags: c#, try-catch, var

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var api = RiotApi.GetInstance("KEY");


        try
        {
            var game = api.GetCurrentGame(RiotSharp.Platform.EUW1, 79200188);
        }

        catch (RiotSharpException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        foreach (var player in game.Participants) // Can't find game variable
        {

        }
    }
```

I can't call game.Participants in my foreach loop because i initialize game inside the try statement. I can't initialize game outside the try statement either though because to do that i would have to give it a temporary value and I don't know what kind of value it will be.

Is there a way to declare a variable as null? Or is there potentially a different way to solve this?

Comment: Something like `Game game = null;`? Please, notice, that you can't put `var game = null;` and have to declare the actual type.

Comment: Consider moving the loop into the try, since you don't want to access games if they dont exist or?

Comment: Whats wrong with including foreach inside the try block?

Comment: The whole `try` block is pointless, because you only ever re-throw the exception anyway.  Just remove the try/catch block as it won't change your code in any way.

Answer (score 5):

You should declare variable before `try-catch` block, otherwise it will not be visible outside the `try-catch` block:

```
TypeOfGame game = null; // declare local variable here
// note that you should provide initial value as well

try
{
   // assigne it here
   game = api.GetCurrentGame(RiotSharp.Platform.EUW1, 79200188);
}
catch (RiotSharpException ex)
{
    // I hope you have some real code here
    throw;
}

// now you can use it 
foreach(var player in game.Participants)
{

}
```

Note that your current `try-catch` block don't catch anything except `RiotSharpException` and even for that type of exceptions you simply rethrow it. So nothing will change if you'll remove `try-catch` completely here

```
var api = RiotApi.GetInstance("KEY");
// if api can be null, then you can use null-propagation operation ?.
var game = api?.GetCurrentGame(RiotSharp.Platform.EUW1, 79200188);
if (game == null) // consider to add null-check
   return;

foreach(var player in game.Participants)
   // ...
```

---

Further reading: [3.7 Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) from C# specification

> The scope of a name is the region of program text within which it is
>   possible to refer to the entity declared by the name without
>   qualification of the name. Scopes can be nested

And especially

> • The scope of a local variable declared in a
>   local-variable-declaration (§8.5.1) is the block in which the
>   declaration occurs.

So when you declare local variable within `try-catch` block, it can be referred only within `try-catch` block. If you declare local variable within method body block, it can be referred within method body scope and within nested scopes.

Comment: Might be an idea to do a null check before the foreach in case the exception is handled in his real code (instead of just throwing)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou agree, also thought about that but in current code in case of any exception we will not get to the loop. I think your comment is a good note fore OP to keep that in mind

Comment: Wouldnt game.Participants in the forloop fall over if the catch is thrown?

Comment: @BadDub sorry, what do you mean by *fall over*? We will not get to that point in case of any exception

Comment: If the game catch is executed, that would leave game as null based on how you initialised it. Then in the foreach loop when you do game.Participants wouldn't it throw a "object is not set to an instance of an object" as the participants link doesnt exist?

Comment: @BadDub as it stands, if an exception is caught, the foreach loop will not be executed because there is a `throw;` in the catch block.

Comment: Well based on the updated answer the try catch has been removed. So I guess it at least applies to that updated answer? EDIT: never mind, I see he checks that the game is null first.

Comment: @BadDub I just assumed that OP has more work to do in catch block - e.g. logging something or notifying user that game is not available (he could just simplify code in question). But if it's not the case - then we can remove try-catch

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var api = RiotApi.GetInstance("KEY");

    // if we have api, try get the game
    var game = api != null 
      ? api.GetCurrentGame(RiotSharp.Platform.EUW1, 79200188)
      : null;

    // if we have game, process the players 
    if (game != null)
        foreach (var player in game.Participants) 
        {
            //TODO: put relevant logic here
        }
}
```

Please, notice, that `try {} catch (RiotSharpException ex) {throw;}` is a *redundant* construction and can be *dropped*.

Comment: Why is it redundant?

Comment: @FastCow: you *catch* the exception and do nothing, but *throw* it again

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this? I dont know what type your `GetCurrentGame` retuns from the api so I just used `GameType` as a placeholder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var api = RiotApi.GetInstance("KEY");

    GameType game = new GameType();        

    try
    {
        game = api.GetCurrentGame(RiotSharp.Platform.EUW1, 79200188);
    }

    catch (RiotSharpException ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    if(game == null || !game.Participants.Any()) return;

    foreach (var player in game.Participants) // Can't find game variable
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work as a placeholder :( The return type is RiotSharp.CurrentgameEndpont.CurrentGame

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
var game = (Object)null;
```

Comment: game is definitely not string

Comment: That just declares `game` as `Object` and then you won't be able to do `foreach (var player in game.Participants)`.

Answer (score -2):

string y = null;

var x = y;

this will work